# spring junit load application context for tests

Tags: spring, junit, applicationcontext

I've got some XML files under my WEB-INF directory:

- lyricsBaseApp-servlet.xml
- hibernate.xml
- dataSource.xml
- beans.xml

the servlet xml imports other xml files:

```
<import resource="dataSource.xml"/>
<import resource="hibernate.xml"/>
<import resource="beans.xml"/>
```

I would like my junit4 `JukeboxTest` class to include entire spring configuration. Using default filename I have created a `JukeboxTest-content.xml` file. And finally, I do not know what to put there...

I've tried:

```
<import resource="/WEB-INF/dataSource.xml"/>
<import resource="/WEB-INF/hibernate.xml"/>
<import resource="/WEB-INF/beans.xml"/>
```

or

```
<import resource="classpath:./WEB-INF/dataSource.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:./WEB-INF/hibernate.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:./WEB-INF/beans.xml"/>
```

and some other ideas but all failed. Could someone point me how to access those files and what way spring interprets those filepaths?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**Option 1** (should be preferred as it's the best practice):
Refactor your config files under `WEB-INF` and move the common parts (that you want to access also from integration tests) to `src/main/resources/`. Then write test specific configuration files in `src/test/resources/` (if you only need to import several different config files from `src/main` to assemble your test context, then skip this, and use `@ContextConfiguration` preferably).

**Option 2** (hack):
Use references like:

```
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dataSource.xml")
```

**Option 3** (hack):
If you have a Maven project, you can configure the `maven-surefire-plugin` (used in the test phase) to declare `src/main/webapp` as an additional classpath element during test execution.

The latter two options are considered as hack, because files under `src/main/webapp` are simply not supposed to be on the classpath.

#### Now the detailed explanation:

The reason why you can't refer to these files as `classpath:/WEB-INF/*.xml` is that they are indeed not on the classpath. It's important to understand how your webapp is packaged, and what exactly ends up on the classpath. Assuming a default Maven project structure:

1. Java classes from `src/main/java` go to `/WEB-INF/classes` after compilation.
2. Resources from `src/main/resources` go to `/WEB-INF/classes` as well.
3. Project dependencies go to `/WEB-INF/lib`.
4. Everything you have in `src/main/webapp` goes to `/` (root of the package). This means that all files from `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` go to `/WEB-INF`, of course.

The most important thing to know is that the classpath will only contain `/WEB-INF/classes` and one entry for each jar in `/WEB-INF/lib`. Consequently, resources outside these two locations are completely invisible for the classloader. This is also true for the xml config files *directly under* `/WEB-INF`, which is why the reference `classpath:/WEB-INF/dataSource.xml` will never work.

You may ask yourself, how the hell are then these xml config files loaded by Spring if they are not reachable from the classpath? The answer is simple: When you start your webapp (as opposed to executing just unit/integration tests), it is running in a Servlet Container which provides access to the `ServletContext` (an actual class from the Servlet API), so it uses `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()` to load these files. The key for understanding is the following quote from the [javadoc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) of this method:

> This method is different from java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream, which uses a class loader. This method allows servlet containers to make a resource available to a servlet from any location, without using a class loader.

Sorry this become way too long, but that's the whole story...

Comment: How to refer to context files in *src/test/resources*? The @Kris' answer was the only one that worked for me.

Comment: Going for option 1 .. how do you then actually load that context file?

Comment: @zagyi how do I declare src/main/webapp as one of the additional classpaths in the test context?

Answer (score 12):

try this

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:**/dataSource.xml",
                               "classpath:**/hibernate.xml", 
                               "classpath:**/WEB-INF/beans.xml"})
```

Comment: This worked for me with application-context.xml in src/test/resources.