# How to load multiple contexts using jUnit and Spring

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a junit test class with following annotations :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:custom-context.xml")
```

There exists a class in another context that is required in my test that is autowired so I require this context to be loaded. How can this be implemented ?

I've tried :

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:custom-context.xml , classpath:custom-context2.xml")
```

But this does now work as it does not seem to load multiple contexts using the `,` delimiter.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946298/spring-junit-load-application-context-for-tests. If you have some similar naming pattern you can use pattern paths too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array of strings, like :

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={ "classpath:custom-context.xml" , "classpath:custom-context2.xml" })
```

from [spring api doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html)

Answer (score 3):

Also can use widcard like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:custom-*.xml" })
```